# Iterating through a string for frequency

Tags: python, iteration

I need to iterate through the strings that I have established by writing 10 random strings to a text file then reading them back in and finding the frequency of each letter in each individual string. I have it up to the point where it reads the file back in but I cant figure out how to find the value of the characters. Any help?

```
import string
import random
from collections import Counter

print "******************************"

print "********* EXERCISE 5 *********"

print "******************************"

print "\n**** BEGIN RANDOM STRING *****\n"


def random_string_generator():
    size = random.randint(20, 80)
    return "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase)
                   for _ in range(size))

def main():
    with open("exercise_five.dat", "w+") as f:
        for x in range(0, 10):
            data = random_string_generator()
            f.write(data + "\n")
        f.close()
    with open("exercise_five.dat", 'r') as f:
        count = 0
        c = Counter()
        for i in f:
            print i
        print "Count: %i" % count

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
print "*******************************"
```

The final output should look something like this:

```
***** BEGIN RANDOM STRING *****
xGYMSlMHGQAMNrSzXWqphkGntMpyjMoHyRDzaNOcmVtoeAZzcV
A ==> 2 D ==> 1 G ==> 3 H ==> 2 M ==> 5 O ==> 1 N ==> 2 Q ==> 1 S ==> 2
R ==> 1 W ==> 1 V ==> 2 Y ==> 1 X ==> 1 Z ==> 1 a ==> 1 c ==> 2 e ==> 1
h ==> 1 k ==> 1 j ==> 1 m ==> 1 l ==> 1 o ==> 2 n ==> 1 q ==> 1 p ==> 2
r ==> 1 t ==> 2 y ==> 2 x ==> 1 z ==> 3
*******************************
```

my code output right now looks like this:

```
**** BEGIN RANDOM STRING *****

QheDRPpVwDnfYWYMJQwEedJsjApRVafvMYUYuepYSerkoMgCTnHLSHwCitBr

zOFvifcwkrwXLxTrodqkxNxWVHdHDJZbYlcYjAUKz

DRgFXVkbtwpRfXPjzJmXYW

mpkVgUyvHEHAKUWpMZBYIKenicfdcBhxlqCZHFgxoFEmJjtrPykCzvQnFkTHfVthII

zEXLmudQVlpVQYexAvGFTBeUuZvqTO

KSRcpBlfNwcMoNViHFhS

QhTiBLuGCsClezAiVFYODiJXAQCQjwnBnHjWqlsZlljA

iYHznFLFeKwLtynubHTRtGGwjACdGlCpZSQcqnTSWVmufpHQRkwWYiajarnqNuzUzSC

NWlGeJFFcYwacXuUHWqmzSJmsrnWRvpmdSesXXmECuvAMkxGYpHv

WVAAiDgGaGnovCbbdazNGmWXARgdSfqCSztsNTPBdLumIXiDh

*******************************
```

Comment: What's your code output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up from where you defined the `Counter`, you can initialize the `Counter` with each line read from the file. That will give you a `Counter` instance which has keys and values, similar to a dictionary:

```
with open("exercise_five.dat", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        c = Counter(line)
        print(' '.join('{} ==> {}'.format(key, val) for key, val in c.items()))
```

A more in-depth explanation of the last line:

```
>>> c = Counter("text")  # initialize a Counter object with the string "text"
>>> c.keys()  # this instance has `keys` and `values`, similar to a dictionary
dict_keys(['e', 't', 'x'])
>>> c.items()  # you can access both keys and values at the same time with `items`
dict_items([('e', 1), ('t', 2), ('x', 1)])
>>> c
Counter({'t': 2, 'e': 1, 'x': 1})
>>> for key, val in c.items():
...     print(key, val)
... 
e 1
t 2
x 1
```

At that point, you merely need to use some string formatting to get the output format you desire, which is what the `print(' '.join(...)` construct does.

Answer (score 1):

[defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a great tool for doing this:

```
import collections

occurrences = collections.defaultdict(int)

word = 'ASDqasdqASD'

for c in word:
    occurrences[c] += 1
print occurrences
> defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'A': 2, 'a': 1, 'D': 2, 's': 1, 'q': 2, 'S': 2, 'd': 1})
```